# Added to iTunes connect, does this mean I have an iOS Developer license?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appium

I'm completely new to iOS development, but I've been asked to write automated tests for an iPhone app on a physical device using Appium. I read that I need an iOS developer license to do this, so I asked my company for one and they added me to iTunes Connect. Does this mean I have a developer license?

When I log into the iOS Dev Center it's asking if I want to join the iOS Developer Program and I can't see a place to create a provisioning profile, so I'm thinking I still need a license.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as long as they keep your name in their group, Your company has an enterprise account. Here is the description.
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/